# Why does input only work if I enter a number?

Tags: python, passwords, python-2.x

I have successfully made a python password system but the password can only be out of numbers, not letters. Here is the coding behind it:

```
    password = str(input("Please enter password to continue: "))
    if password == 'dog':
        print ("Welcome")
    else:
        print ("WRONG PASSWORD")
```

This doesn't work while having the password be an integer does work.

Edit: Sorry about putting the wrong code, new to this site.
I have now added quotes to 'dog' but it now gives this error in terminal

```
Please enter password to continue: dog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pass.py", line 1, in <module>
    password = str(input("Please enter password to continue: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dog' is not defined
```

Final edit: Fixed it by changing str(input to str(raw_input. It was because I was using terminal which uses python 2. Does anyone know how to make terminal do python 3 instead of 2?

Comment: are you looking for `password == '123'` ?

Comment: Please show the code that fails, not the code that works.

Comment: if password == "dog"

Comment: Python thinks that `dog` is a variable name, you need to quote it, for example:  `if password == "dog":`

Comment: Of interest might be the standard library module `getpass`.   Replace the call to `input()` with `getpass.getpass()`.  Also, if you want to check that a string is  digits, try `password.isdigit()`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass a `string` type to an `integer`, which will not work. You can compare a string to an int!

Strings in python need speech marks (`"STRING"`) around them. If there are no speech marks, python will assume it is an integer or float.

Your correct code should be:

```
password = str(input("Please enter password to continue: "))
if password == "dog":
    print ("Welcome")
else:
    print ("WRONG PASSWORD")
```

EDIT:
It also appears that you are using Python 2 (because you are using terminal). The `input` function in Python 2 tries to get input as a python expression, not as a string. Try using `raw_input` instead, if you are using Python 2. This will get the input as a string.

The string speech marks still applies. Your code would look like:

```
password = str(raw_input("Please enter password to continue: "))
if password == "dog":
    print ("Welcome")
else:
    print ("WRONG PASSWORD")
```

Comment: I added quotes but it still gives an error in terminal, I just added the error in the question.

Comment: The raw_input way worked! Thanks, earlier I had gotten rid of the str part when doing raw_input so it failed but now it works.
Quick question though: Is there a way to get python 3 to work on terminal? And also is code academy teaching python 3 or 2, and if it is teaching 2 where do you think I should learn 3?

Comment: If you want to use Python 3 (which I recommend by the way) you should just download IDLE from the python website. I don't think terminal can work with 3, but getting IDLE is simple. I've had a quick look, and yes it look like CodeAcademny teaches python 3.

Comment: How do I run the script though? I downloaded python 3.5.2 from the website but i don't know how to run the script.

Comment: Hit F5. Google may be a valuable resource. See some basic YouTube tutorials; these are quite informative.

Comment: Just figured out how to use everything. Works pretty well, working right now on a new thing where the person actually creates the username and password first. Definitley will look around on youtube and stuff to find good resources.

Answer (score 0):

"Types" are the key here.

You're casting the input you get from the user (which is a String) to `int` - Integer:

```
3 == '3'
```

That's False! a String can never be equal to an Integer.

I would advise not casting it to `int`, keep it a `str` and it should work just fine.

Comment: When the correct password is a number like 123 it works, but if i change it to for instance 'dog' it gives this error:

        Please enter password to continue: dog
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "pass.py", line 1, in <module>
            password = str(input("Please enter password to continue: "))
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        NameError: name 'dog' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

To make it non-recurring:

```
password="dog"
password1=input("Enter password?")
if password==password1:
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print("Incorrect password")
```

However to make it rcurring you just do this:

```
condition = True
password="dog"
while condition:
    password1=input("Enter password?")
    if password==password1:
        print("Welcome")
    else:
        print("Incorrect password")
```

Comment: Uh... "pass" is an in-built keyword so if you use it as a variable so it won't work and instead it will raise an error

Comment: Oh, yea, that is a problem I did not think about, all that's needed though is change pass to another variable.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using python 2, try using:

```
inp = str(raw_input('Please enter password to continue: '))
print("Welcome") if password == "password_here" else print ("WRONG PASSWORD")
```

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and the one given by MagikCow back in 2017?

Comment: @RubioRic It omits the redundant conversion to ``str``. ``raw_input`` already returns uninterpreted strings.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks! I think that point should be exposed and highlighted in the text.

Comment: @rubicrio try again now. I had forgotten to insert one statement. And now it forests takes input, and THEN concerts it to string.